# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this Uncaught TypeError:

[image]

I'm unsure what is causing it, maybes something to do with JQuery?

Here is the exact code:

```
//when add to cart link is clicked...
$('.addtocart').on('click', function(){

  //get the value of the "data-value" attribute for that link
  var vehicleRegistration = $(this).data('value');
  //save it to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('vehicleRegistration', vehicleRegistration);


  //read from localStorage
  if( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') ){
    //add the value to the form input
    $('#field34').val( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') );
  }

});
```

Here is the page that it is happening on: http://drivencarsales.co.uk/book-testdrive

It's really got me stumped, if anyone can help me solve this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: and please put your html element with this class either

Comment: also make sure your jquery version is equal to or more than `1.7`

Comment: You should show the HTML declaration as well

Comment: Make sure that JQuery is loaded before running that code

Comment: I think this is probably because there is no such `.addtocart` element in your HTML structure. you probably want to target `.btn-cart` element. In addition to that, you have a conflict between `jQuery` and `prototype` as indicated by the two answers below. So you may want to use this: `jQuery('.btn-cart').on('click', function(){ ... });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site, you have both `prototype.js` and `jQuery` added. The `$` here calls `prototype.js` instead of `jQuery`. So instead of that code, please change it to:

```
jQuery('.addtocart').on('click', function(){

  //get the value of the "data-value" attribute for that link
  var vehicleRegistration = jQuery(this).data('value');
  //save it to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('vehicleRegistration', vehicleRegistration);


  //read from localStorage
  if( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') ){
    //add the value to the form input
    jQuery('#field34').val( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') );
  }

});
```

Or you can also do this:

```
(function ($) {
    $('.addtocart').on('click', function(){

      //get the value of the "data-value" attribute for that link
      var vehicleRegistration = $(this).data('value');
      //save it to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('vehicleRegistration', vehicleRegistration);


      //read from localStorage
      if( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') ){
        //add the value to the form input
        $('#field34').val( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') );
      }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$`. Your $ is getting conflict with jQuery and prototypejs.

Whenever you write jQuery code, try using self invocation function with jQuery as parameter.

for Ex.

```
(function($){//You can use any character instead $ here.
//Your code here to use $. 
})(jQuery);
```

or another way is use `jQuery` word instead of `$`.

for Ex.

```
jQuery('.addtocart').on('click', function(){
  //Your code here.
});
```

In your code, `$` is used by prototype, `$('.addtocart')` is returning null as there are no elements with class .addtocart when this script gets executed. and thats why it is throwing error while accessing on of null*($('.addtocart'))*.

If you want to add eventhandler with jquery Only. then use jQuery word instead $.

```
//when add to cart link is clicked...
jQuery('.addtocart').on('click', function(){

  //get the value of the "data-value" attribute for that link
  var vehicleRegistration = jQuery(this).data('value');
  //save it to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('vehicleRegistration', vehicleRegistration);


  //read from localStorage
  if( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') ){
    //add the value to the form input
    jQuery('#field34').val( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') );
  }

});
```