# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null at home

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a hamburger menu but I get this error message.

[Here is a picture of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUJXb.png)

I am just new with jquery and therefore have no idea what the problem is.

This is my jquery code:

```
<script id="rendered-js">
  $("button").on("click", function () {
  $("body").toggleClass("open");
});
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<button class="menu-toggle show-in-mobile"></button>
    <nav class="menu show-in-mobile">
        <ul>

            <li>
                <a class="active" href="/en/support/home">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="" href="/en/support/solutions">Solutions</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="" href="/en/support/discussions">Forums</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="" href="/en/support/tickets">Tickets</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And this is my head:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://assets10.freshdesk.com/assets/cdn/preview-6f0bb8c39775981205d4259fd3f72cf4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Someone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: If you click on the 'home:101' in your error message it should take you to the location of the error. What exactly is that 'home' file?

Comment: The very first thing I'd do is change the protocol to `https` in the jQuery URL. Next, `$()` returning `null` seems weird; can you create a [mre]? This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/d53k4c6s/

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the button will update the post. @mind  when I click on 'home' I end up with the javascript code.

Comment: @ChrisG Ok give me a min.

Comment: I would like to see the code at line 101

Comment: @ChrisG look at your fiddle. It works there, but not on my website..

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui Told you i'm new ;p The code at line 101 is this: `$("button").on("click", function ()`

Comment: This line shouldn't throw that error, there is something. Can you post complete html page ?

Comment: Well jQuery does not return null so my guess is `$` is not jQuery

Comment: @epascarello  in that case it will be :  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3rgbymd0/) Here it is, it is too much for this post

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui um, not if it is overwritten by something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is some other library used in your HEAD which is conflicting with jQuery

Similar question has a well written accepted answer here:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033591/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-on-of-null)

**Update**

It turns out to be issue with following url included
https://assets4.freshdesk.com/assets/cdn/portal_head-cc545c114f8f15358aa7acd4b9de11a5.js

Comment: so this should be a dupe, not an answer....

Comment: @WimTH do clear about the conflicts here, so in future it will help others.